# R: How to assign a value in a dataframe column based in rows selected by some criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a dataframe like:

```
> head(bedfile)
                        chr start   end                        fam    class_subclass Jval_at_closing step strand    code            family
1 1.1000_SRR13070663.317319   582   665      LINE__rnd-6_family-16     LINE/I-Jockey               2    3      R    LINE   rnd-6_family-16
2 1.1000_SRR13070663.317319 20701 20804    LINE__rnd-5_family-6279           LINE/L2               3    2      F    LINE rnd-5_family-6279
3 1.1001_SRR13070663.317930  1023  1117     DNA__rnd-5_family-1403 DNA/TcMar-Mariner               2    3      R     DNA rnd-5_family-1403
4 1.1001_SRR13070663.317930  1139  1196 Unknown__rnd-5_family-4199           Unknown               3    3      F Unknown rnd-5_family-4199
5 1.1001_SRR13070663.317930  1199  1282 Unknown__rnd-5_family-6039           Unknown               4    3      R Unknown rnd-5_family-6039
6 1.1001_SRR13070663.317930  1317  1384 Unknown__rnd-6_family-2340           Unknown               5    3      F Unknown rnd-6_family-2340
```

and another one:

```
> head(CODE)
      V1 V2 V3  V4 V5
1   rDNA  F  S 500  3
2   rDNA  R  s 500  3
3 CL0015  F  O 300  3
4 CL0015  R  o 300  3
5 CL0076  F  P 300  3
6 CL0076  R  p 300  3
```

I would like to create a new column in the first one, and assign different values to selected rows based on criteria, using a nested for loop that creates the criteria:

```
    for (i in unique(CODE$V1)) {
        for (j in unique(CODE$V2)) {
                bedfile[bedfile$code == i & bedfile$strand == j,]$codification <- CODE[CODE$V1 == i & CODE$V2 == j,]$V3}}
```

The idea is that a particular value from one dataframe to be assigned to all rows that match these criteria in `bedfile`, but the actual code does not work. The problem is in the assignation line, since the following statement does not work either:

```
bedfile[bedfile$code == "LTR" & bedfile$strand == "+",]$codification <- "some_string"
```

Can anyone help me? I think that it may be also a way more efficient way for do that than with a nested for loop, but I don't know how

Thank you

Comment: This is a "merge" or "join" operation. In base R, `merge(bedfile, CODE[c("V1", "V2", "V3")], by.x = c("code", "strand"), by.y = c("V1", "V2"), all.x = TRUE)`. Or with `library(dplyr)` you can do `left_join(bedfile, select(CODE, V1, V2, codification = V3), on = c("code" = "V1", "strand" = "V2"))`

Comment: That's awesome, thank you @GregorThomas !